# object of type interface undefined

Tags: angular

I want to create and initialize an object of type interface IClassificationOverride.  I am getting runtime error that object in not defined. I am not able to understand what is the problem here. If you see below I am initializing and object of type IClassificationOverride

```js
classificationOverride: IClassificationOverride;
this.classificationOverride.ManagerStrategyId =  this.managerStrategyId;
this.classificationOverride.ProductId = this.selectedProductItem.Id;
this.classificationOverride.LegacyStrategyId = this.selectedReportingItem.Id;
this.classificationOverride.ManagerStrategyTypeId = this.selectedStrategyItem.Id;
```

Interface

```js
    export interface IClassificationOverride {
    ID: number;
    ManagerStrategyId: number;
    ProductId: number;
    StrategyId: number;
    LegacyStrategyId: number;
    ManagerStrategyTypeId: number;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
classificationOverride: IClassificationOverride;
```

just declares the type of your variable. It does not create the object (that's why value is still `undefined`).

You need to actually create an object of this type:

```
classificationOverride = new IClassificationOverride();
```

Buuuut, it does not work since you use an `interface` and not a `class`.

So, you need to create the object yourself:

```
classificationOverride = <IClassificationOverride>{
  ManagerStrategyId: this.managerStrategyId,
  ProductId: this.selectedProductItem.Id,
  /* ... */
}
```